# Is it possible to add Color Shadow to TextInput in react native

Tags: react-native, shadow, textinput

I want to know how to add color shadow to TextInput in react native.
Especially, I mean *color* shadow.
In Android, ShadowColor or Elevation is not working for color shadow.
And the height of TextInput is changable.

I tried the following code for the style to TextInput.

```
shadowColor: 'rgb(112, 0, 0)',
shadowOpacity: 0.12,
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
shadowRadius: 2,
elevation: 2,
```

But it doesn't work on Android.

If you have any good experience and any opinion, please tell me.
I look forward to your kind assistance.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you share some code so we know what you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cardview

```
$ npm install react-native-cardview --save


import CardView from 'react-native-cardview';

<CardView
 cardElevation={2}
 cardMaxElevation={2}
 cornerRadius={5}>
     <TextInput/>
</CardView>
```

This library does not control shadow color
For this library you can use this directory

https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to add Color to this shadow?

Comment: Thanks. As I said before, the height of text input is changeable. How can I fix it. In other words, I can't give certain height to BoxShadow component's setting props.